Необходимо выводить новый текст сообщения после двух одинаковых
Я создаю чат бот на php. У меня есть скрипт вывода сообщений чат бота. Мне необходимо реализовать так, чтобы после двух сообщений чат бота "Я не понимаю вас!" выводилось другое сообщение.Например, "Если вы не можете найти вопрос, напишите нам в телеграмм". Пока только выводиться одно сообщение каждый раз после неудачных попыток.
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig/config.php';

$stmt = $db->quote($_POST['txt']);
$sql="SELECT answer FROM `chatbot_shop` WHERE client_question LIKE $stmt";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $content = $row['answer'];
}else{
        $content = "Я вас не понимаю";
}





$result->closeCursor();

$added_on=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO message(message,type) VALUES('$content','consultant')");


$added_on=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO message(message,type) VALUES('$stmt','client')");

echo $content;
echo " ";
?>


Код, который вы написали в вопросе, не имеет смысла и сам по себе, и в контексте заданного вопроса.  В вопросе у вас написано "выводить текст", а в коде - записывать в базу данных

Хорошо, а как лучше описать данный вопрос? И с самим кодом может нужно как то по другому написать?

Для начала надо научиться сохранять состояние. то есть помнить историю разговора. Но в самую первую очередь надо научиться пользоваться функцией prepare. Потому что сейчас вы ей пользуетесь как обезьяна микроскопом.
